# Convert JS function to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I need to convert a JS function to PHP

Here is JS function

```
function urlDecode(str){
    str=str.replace(new RegExp('\\+','g'),' ');
    return unescape(str);
}
```

Thanks

Riz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) is a native php function.

Comment: It is in javascript too, oh well not for URLs but URIs: decodeURI() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp That one catches a lot more than only '+' -> ' '